# Trying to find length of text within div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find the length of text (ie. number of characters) of text within a specified div (#post_div) EXCLUDING HTML formatting AND the content of a NON specific span . So any embedded span that is NOT #span1 #span2 needs to be excluded from the count.

So far I have the following solution which works, but it adds/removes from the DOM which I would prefer not to do.

```
 var post = $("#post_div");
 var post2 = post.html(); //duplicating for later
 post.find("span:not(#span1):not(#span2)").remove(); //removing unwanted (only for character count) spans from DOM - YUCK!
 post = $.trim(post.text());
 console.log(post.length);  // The correct length is here.
 $("#post_div").html(post2); //replacing butchered DIV with original duplicate in DOM - YUCK!
```

I would prefer to achieve the same result, but without butchering the DOM/adding/replacing things from it for a simple character count.

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of duplicating the HTML then working on the original node, duplicate the node and work on it outside of the main DOM tree.

```
var post = $("#post_div").clone();
post.find("span:not(.post_tag):not(.post_mentioned)").remove();
post = $.trim(post.text());
console.log(post.length); // The correct length is here.
```

Comment: Thanks. Does the clone get added to the DOM (ie. displayed on the screen somewhere) and thus need to be removed too? I'd prefer not to be altering the DOM if possible....dunno just seems messy for such a small things as counting characters.

Comment: Nope. The clone is a detached node, so is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the simple

```
var t = $.trim($("#post_div span.post_tag, #post_div span.post_mentioned").text());
console.log(t.length);
```

Should Suffice.

However, if you have textual content Outside of span Elements, you would have to use

```
var t       = $.trim($("#post_div").text());
var t_inner = $("#post_div span:not(.post_tag):not(.post_mentioned)").text());
console.log(t.length - t_inner.length);
```

Comment: Unless there's content not in a span that also needs to be counted.

Comment: Correct, content in the main DIV (#post_div) plus content in #span1 and #span2 needs to be counted and anything else EXCEPT content in any other SPAN needs to be excluded.

Comment: @simon_w yes, i was complementing the answer to handle this case while your comment arrived, thanks nonetheless.